# Still getting a "Restricted shell escape" on Kile

Tags: ubuntu, gnuplot, shell-escape, kile

In order to add gnuplots in my documents, I'm using this basic code to verify my system (Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS + Kile 2.9.93)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
  \usepackage{shellesc}
  \begin{document}

  \ifcase\ShellEscapeStatus
    No shell escape\or
    Unrestricted shell escape\or
    Restricted shell escape%
  \fi
\end{document}
```

and it still prints me *Restricted shell escape* (even though I configured Kile properly, adding the "-shell-escape" attribute on pdfLaTeX building tab.

[image]

The same code running on Overleaf (obviously) prints *Unrestricted shell escape*.

I spent hours on the web hoping to find a solution, even trying to change the `texmf.cnf` file, apparently located in my system at `/etc/texmf/web2c`, but it only contains:

```
%%% This file is automatically generated by update-texmf
%
% PLEASE DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE DIRECTLY. It is meant to be generated from 
% files in /etc/texmf/texmf.d/. 
% Therefore, if you want a smooth upgrade, please edit the files
% in /etc/texmf/texmf.d, 
% or create an additional one (with the extension '.cnf'),
% and invoke update-texmf.
%
%%%
%%% From file: /etc/texmf/texmf.d/00debian.cnf
VARTEXFONTS=/tmp/texfonts
%%% End of file: /etc/texmf/texmf.d/00debian.cnf
```

The log file shows this:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2022.5.2)  10 MAY 2023 12:05
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**shellescape.tex
(./shellescape.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-01-21>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/standalone/standalone.cls
Document Class: standalone 2018/03/26 v1.3a Class to compile TeX sub-files stan
dalone
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/shellesc.sty
Package: shellesc 2019/11/08 v1.0c unified shell escape interface for LaTeX
Package shellesc Info: Unrestricted shell escape enabled on input line 75.
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2019/10/25 v1.5 ifluatex legacy package. Use iftex instead.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2020/11/20 v2.8 package option processing (HA)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks16
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks17

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))
\XKV@depth=\count185
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
\sa@internal=\count186
\c@sapage=\count187

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/standalone/standalone.cfg
File: standalone.cfg 2018/03/26 v1.3a Default configuration file for 'standalon
e' class
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count188
\c@section=\count189
\c@subsection=\count190
\c@subsubsection=\count191
\c@paragraph=\count192
\c@subparagraph=\count193
\c@figure=\count194
\c@table=\count195
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
)
\sa@box=\box50
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2022-01-12 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count196
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box51
)
(./shellescape.aux)
\openout1 = `shellescape.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
 [1

{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./shellescape.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 998 strings out of 478287
 18798 string characters out of 5849290
 305309 words of memory out of 5000000
 19247 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 469259 words of font info for 28 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 55i,5n,71p,213b,102s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts
/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on shellescape.pdf (1 page, 13563 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 13 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 7 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Any hints, please?

Comment: It would of course be useful to know how you have configured Kile. Just to check your claim `even though I configured Kile properly`

Comment: Additionally exactly which LaTeX have you installed? It is listed in the log. Your example works fine for me on Ubuntu 18.04 using upstream TeXLive 2023.

Comment: I've just edited my question with a screenshot of Kile configuration

Comment: What does the top of your log file say? The status is listed there as well. And what happens if you compile by hand from the commandline  (just to take Kile of of the equation)

Comment: That is not from the top, and please add it to your question (comments are not good at formatting text like this). Without `-shell-escape` I have ` restricted \write18 enabled.` among the top lines.

Comment: I just tested using upsteam TL22 and TL21 both works as advertised. Note I changed your example to write those texts to the console instead. That makes it faster to test.

Comment: I've just edited my question, adding the full log file message

Comment: so your log shows no problem pdftex itself `\write18 enabled.` and shellesc package `Package shellesc Info: Unrestricted shell escape enabled on input line 75`  report shell escape is enabled

Comment: Yeah, I know. But why the heck isn't still working on my computer? Do I have to change some kind of cnf file on Linux?

Comment: It _is_ working on your computer, your log shows shell escape enabled,

Comment: Sorry, it isn't because it still prints me the message "Restricted shell escape" and I cannot compile another document with gnuplot, working perfeclty on Overleaf instead

Comment: change your document so it does a `\typeout` message as well as printing to the pdf then (if you are really looking at the same document) the log should show write18 enabled at the start and then the typeout saying `restricted` in your test in the document. That is not supposed to happen but we will see......

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145917/discussion-between-jj-henry-and-david-carlisle).